# Query error MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which calls table columns and also calculates a distance between objects but I'm showing error on last line near `group by` but cannot see why?

```
SELECT *, filename, c.name as category, d.name as parent,
            ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(53) ) * cos( radians( i.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( i.longitude ) - radians(-0.1) ) + sin( radians(53) )
            * sin( radians( i.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance from items i 
            join item_images ii on i.item_id=ii.item_id
            join categories c on i.category=c.category_id
            join categories d on i.cat_parent=d.category_id
            HAVING distance < 15 
            group by i.item_id order by distance limit 18
```

Comment: What's the error message ?

Comment: `group by` needs to come before `having`.

Comment: order of operation is wrong. FROM JOIN WHERE GROUP BY HAVING ORDER BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch order of clauses: first is GROUP BY, then it follows HAVING.

Comment: Arrgh! I knew the query was right, you are correct, many thanks

Comment: I mean "kind of"/"close to" right! (averting flaming) Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should have the "GROUP BY" before the "HAVING".

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html